# How do you do a query with date-range?

Tags: google-sheets, date-range

In Google Sheets:

A1 = the first day of the month. 
B1 = last day of the month.

```
=QUERY("All!,"A:Z",select Col4 where Col4 >=&A1& AND Col4 <=&B1)")
```

Why won't this work?

Answer (score 0):

See if this works

```
=QUERY(All!A:D, "Select D where toDate(D) >= date '"&TEXT(A1, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'  and toDate(D) <= date '"&TEXT(B1, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'")
```

Comment: Thank you. It says, Error
Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: PARSE_ERROR: Encountered " "toDate" "todate "" at line 1, column 16. Was expecting one of: "(" ... "("

Comment: Updated the formula.

Answer (score 0):

`QUERY` does not understand dates unless they are in `yyyy-mm-dd` format:

```
=QUERY({All!A:Z}, "select Col4 
                   where Col4 >= date '"&TEXT(A1, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
                     and Col4 <= date '"&TEXT(B1, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'", 0)
```